# Beamer presentation: Problem with captions

Tags: beamer, captions, subcaption

I am making a presentation and I have two issues there:
1) I need to use the package subcaption to make subfigures, while simultaneously I want to use the command from this site `\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\raggedright\insertcaption\par}` to get rid of "Figure:" before the figure caption. However, when I use the package subcaption, the latter command stops working and I can still see "Figure:" before the caption - see the first image.
[image]

Do you know how to make "Figure:" dissapear and still use subcaption package?

2) Why is the distance between caption and the figure so long in the image below? (last few lines of the code)
[image]
The code for this figure is the same as the code for the first figure, so I don't understand why there are such differences in the distance of caption from the figure.

The code is:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\documentclass[xcolor=svgnames]{beamer}

%\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
%\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
%
% Choose how your presentation looks.
%
% For more themes, color themes and font themes, see:
% http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/index_by_theme.html
%
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
%\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=NavyBlue}
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}% for better rules in the table
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\title[Thesis Defense]{Name of thesis}
\subtitle{Thesis Defense}
\author{name}
 \institute{University}
\date{January 31, 2018}

\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\raggedright\insertcaption\par}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\tiny}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{-2pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{6pt}



\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Motivation}
\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering

\begin{measuredfigure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.5\textheight,keepaspectratio]{WuXia_rate_Real_HPI}
\caption{\textit{Shaded area marks the pre-crisis period in which effective federal funds rate was below the Taylor rule rate.}}
\end{measuredfigure}

\end{figure}

\begin{itemize}
\item 
\item 
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Results - Impulse responses, baseline model}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\begin{footnotesize}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight,width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{IRF_baseline_big_November2006}
%  \vspace{-3mm}
%
%  \hspace{5mm} \small{November 2006}
  %\caption{November 2006}
  %\label{fig:}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight,width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{IRF_baseline_big_July2007}
%  \vspace{-3mm}
%
%  %\caption{}
%  \hspace{5mm} \small{July 2007}
  %\label{fig:}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight,width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{IRF_baseline_small_October2008}
%  \vspace{-6mm}
%
%  %\caption{}
%  \hspace{5mm} \small{October 2008}
  %\label{fig:}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight,width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{IRF_baseline_big_August2011}
%  \vspace{-6mm}
%
% % \caption{}
% \hspace{5mm} \small{August 2011}
  %\label{fig:}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight,width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{IRF_baseline_small_December2013}
%  \vspace{-6mm}
%
%  %\caption{}
%  \hspace{5mm} \small{December 2013}
  %\label{fig:}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight,width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{IRF_baseline_small_April2017}
%  \vspace{-6mm}
%
%  %\caption{}
%  \hspace{5mm} \small{April 2017}
  %\label{fig:}
\end{subfigure}
%\label{fig:IRF_baseline}
\end{footnotesize}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Results - FEVD}

\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering

\begin{measuredfigure}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{FEVD_baseline_small_April2017}
\caption{Some caption...}
\end{measuredfigure}

\end{figure}


\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Why use `figure` environments at all? They are used for dynamic adjustment of positions, and you don't need that in a beamer presentation. Just use `\includegraphics` and put captions e.g. into `center` environments, and align everything with the `column` environment and similar `beamer`-specific things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of the `subcaption` package you could simply use beamers column mechanism in order to place your images.

Please note that you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}`, `\usepackage{hyperref}` or `\usepackage{xcolor}` with beamer. `\usecolortheme{default}` and `\usefonttheme{default}` are called default, because they are loaded per default, so no need to load them a second time. And giving floating specifier (such as `[!htb]`) does not make sense in a class that does not have floating objects.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\documentclass[xcolor=svgnames]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}  
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}% for better rules in the table
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
%\usepackage{subcaption}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\raggedright\insertcaption\par}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\tiny}
%\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{-2pt}
%\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{6pt}

\title[Thesis Defense]{Name of thesis}
\subtitle{Thesis Defense}
\author{name}
\institute{University}
\date{January 31, 2018}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Results - Impulse responses, baseline model}

\begin{figure}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\footnotesize}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight,width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
        \includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight,width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
        \includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight,width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight,width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
        \includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight,width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
        \includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight,width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
    \end{column}    
\end{columns}   
\caption{whatever caption you want}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for nice answer, but ... what to do when i like to have two subfigures with own subcaption? is there beamer template similar as it is for `caption`? my search so far was not fruitful :-(

Comment: @Zarko Thank you for the vote! One could simply place the subcaption text manually at the end of the columns. Or one could add a new beamertemplate. (maybe I can look into this later this evening)

Comment: @Zarko How about using `\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamerfont{subcaption}{size=\tiny}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{simple}{\usebeamerfont{subcaption}#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}  
 \begin{figure}
  \subcaptionbox{Original}{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image}}
  \subcaptionbox{New}{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image}}
  \caption{Image}
 \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
`?

Comment: thank you very much! i learn something new about beamer. you should enjoy to beamer's maintainer team :-)

Comment: @Zarko You're welcome! FYI: I submitted a feature request for the caption package to use the caption font for the subcation: https://github.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/4